# Display only Subcategories if i call particular category

Tags: magento-1.9, third-party-module

I am displaying all Custom Categories & its sub-categories in Json format with help of below code....

Note : These Categories & its sub-categories are created using [custom module](https://github.com/tzyganu/UMC1.9)

```
<?php

require_once('app/Mage.php');
Mage::app();

$cat_model = Mage::getModel('ultimate_mars/category');
$_categories = $cat_model->getTreeModel()->getCollection()->addFieldToFilter("entity_id", array('gt' => 1));

$category = array();
foreach($_categories as $_category)
{
    $category[] = array("name" => $_category->getCategoryname(), "id" => $_category->getEntityId());
}

echo json_encode($category);
```

**Result** :

[image]

**What i need** :

If i **pass particular category id** [say Tshirts id] in Url, than i need to display **only its sub-categories** [ say Men & Women ] in JSON format....

app/code/local/Ultimate/Mars/Model - **Category.php**

```
<?php

    class Ultimate_Mars_Model_Category extends Mage_Core_Model_Abstract
    {

        const ENTITY    = 'ultimate_mars_category';
        const CACHE_TAG = 'ultimate_mars_category';

        protected $_eventPrefix = 'ultimate_mars_category';

        protected $_eventObject = 'category';

        public function _construct()
        {
            parent::_construct();
            $this->_init('ultimate_mars/category');
        }

        public function getSelectedProductsCollection()
        {
            if (!$this->hasData('_product_collection')) {
                if (!$this->getId()) {
                    return new Varien_Data_Collection();
                } else {
                    $collection = Mage::getResourceModel('ultimate_mars/product_collection')
                            ->addFieldToFilter('category_id', $this->getId());
                    $this->setData('_product_collection', $collection);
                }
            }
            return $this->getData('_product_collection');
        }

        public function getTreeModel()
        {
            return Mage::getResourceModel('ultimate_mars/category_tree');
        }

        public function getTreeModelInstance()
        {
            if (is_null($this->_treeModel)) {
                $this->_treeModel = Mage::getResourceSingleton('ultimate_mars/category_tree');
            }
            return $this->_treeModel;
        }

        public function getParentCategory()
        {
            if (!$this->hasData('parent_category')) {
                $this->setData(
                    'parent_category',
                    Mage::getModel('ultimate_mars/category')->load($this->getParentId())
                );
            }
            return $this->_getData('parent_category');
        }

        public function getParentId()
        {
            $parentIds = $this->getParentIds();
            return intval(array_pop($parentIds));
        }


        public function getParentIds()
        {
            return array_diff($this->getPathIds(), array($this->getId()));
        }


        public function getAllChildren($asArray = false)
        {
            $children = $this->getResource()->getAllChildren($this);
            if ($asArray) {
                return $children;
            } else {
                return implode(',', $children);
            }
        }

        public function getChildCategorys()
        {
            return implode(',', $this->getResource()->getChildren($this, false));
        }


        public function checkId($id)
        {
            return $this->_getResource()->checkId($id);
        }


        public function getPathIds()
        {
            $ids = $this->getData('path_ids');
            if (is_null($ids)) {
                $ids = explode('/', $this->getPath());
                $this->setData('path_ids', $ids);
            }
            return $ids;
        }

        public function getLevel()
        {
            if (!$this->hasLevel()) {
                return count(explode('/', $this->getPath())) - 1;
            }
            return $this->getData('level');
        }


        public function verifyIds(array $ids)
        {
            return $this->getResource()->verifyIds($ids);
        }

        public function hasChildren()
        {
            return $this->_getResource()->getChildrenAmount($this) > 0;
        }

        public function getCategorys($parent, $recursionLevel = 0, $sorted=false, $asCollection=false, $toLoad=true)
        {
            return $this->getResource()->getCategorys($parent, $recursionLevel, $sorted, $asCollection, $toLoad);
        }


        public function getParentCategorys()
        {
            return $this->getResource()->getParentCategorys($this);
        }


        public function getChildrenCategorys()
        {
            return $this->getResource()->getChildrenCategorys($this);
        }


        public function getStatusPath()
        {
            $parents = $this->getParentCategorys();
            $rootId = Mage::helper('ultimate_mars/category')->getRootCategoryId();
            foreach ($parents as $parent) {
                if ($parent->getId() == $rootId) {
                    continue;
                }
                if (!$parent->getStatus()) {
                    return false;
                }
            }
            return $this->getStatus();
        }        
    }
```

[Here is link to Download module](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1em4p6d2FJyu8mQ7GQDlHlwIUtDwReAvc) : [link](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1em4p6d2FJyu8mQ7GQDlHlwIUtDwReAvc)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use below code to get sub category of category tshirt

```
<?php

error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);

require_once('app/Mage.php');
Mage::app();


$cat_model = Mage::getModel('ultimate_mars/category');
$reqCat = (int)$_REQUEST['category_id'];
if ($reqCat > 0) {



    $_cate = $cat_model->getTreeModel()->getCollection()->addFilter("parent_id", $reqCat);



} else {
    $_cate = $cat_model->getTreeModel()->getCollection()->addFieldToFilter("entity_id", array('gt' => 1));
}


$category = array();
foreach ($_cate as $_category) {
    $category[] = array("name" => $_category->getCategoryname(), "id" => $_category->getEntityId());
}

echo json_encode($category);
```

Comment: thanks for answer, 

we are entering category_id in php code , instead of that , category_id should be in url.....

when we pass the category id in url , than only it should display result....

something like below :

ex : `http://sbdev1.kidsdial.com/cat8.php?category_id="2"`

Comment: can you please tell how to access url , i tried like this : http:// example.com/cat8.php?category_id="2"

Comment: http://sbdev1.kidsdial.com/cat8.php?category_id=2

Comment: http://sbdev1.kidsdial.com/cat8.php?category_id=5

Answer (score 2):

```
$parentCatId = 1;// pass your required category id here

$category = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')
        load($parentCatId)
        ;


$subcats = $category->getChildren();


 $subcat=array();
foreach(explode(',',$subcats) as $subCatid)
{
  $_category = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($subCatid);
  if($_category->getIsActive())
  {
     $image = $_category->getImageUrl();

    $subcat[]=array(
           "id"=>$_category->getId(), 
           "url"=>($_category->getURL())  ? $_category->getURL() : "", 
            "name"=>($_category->getName())  ? $_category->getName() : "",
            "meta_title"=>($_category->getMetaTitle())  ? $_category->getMetaTitle(): "", 
            "meta_keywords"=>($_category->getMetaKeywords())  ? $_category->getMetaKeywords(): "",
            "meta_description"=>($_category->getMetaDescription())  ? $_category->getMetaDescription(): "",
            "image_url"=>($image)  ? $image: "",
    );

  }
```

Comment: Thanks, your code is for magento default categories , i am using custom module to create categories, please check code i posted in question....

Answer (score 2):

Can you replace below code

```
$_categories = $cat_model->getTreeModel()->getCollection()->addFieldToFilter("entity_id", array('gt' => 1));
```

with

```
$_categories = $cat_model->getTreeModel()->getCollection()->addFieldToFilter("entity_id", array('eq' => 2));
```

I have not checked this but it should help you.

Comment: Thanks for answer, its displaying result [{"name":"Tshirts","id":"2"}] means when we **pass category_id : 2 in url** , its displaying only category_id 2 , but what i need is to when we **pass category_id : 2 in url** , it should display only its subcategories , i.e Men & Women.....

Answer (score 1):

Try this code working fine for me

```
<?php require_once('app/Mage.php');
Mage::app();

$categryId = 2; /* Your requested category ID */ 
$yourCategory = Mage::getModel('ultimate_mars/category')->load($categryId);

$childLevel = (int)$yourCategory->getData("categorylevel") + 1;
/* Getting subcategory of requested category id */
$cat_model = Mage::getModel('ultimate_mars/category');
$_categories = $cat_model->getTreeModel()->getCollection()->addFieldToFilter("parent_id",$yourCategory->getId())->addFieldToFilter("categorylevel",$childLevel);

$category = array();
foreach($_categories as $_category)
{
    $category[] = array("name" => $_category->getCategoryname(), "id" => $_category->getEntityId());
}

echo json_encode($category);
```

Comment: Hi, Thanks for your help, i tried your code, i got result as  : `[{"name":"Women","id":"4"}]` means i have `3 subcategories` for `category id- 2` , in that only 1 subcategory displayed : `[{"name":"Women","id":"4"}]`, but i already got answer for this question from other answer by user jigs parmar....